# How to include the wp-config file from a folder deeper in the site tree

Tags: php, wordpress

I don't know why I always have to much trouble including PHP files. In this case all I'm trying to do is include the `wp-config` file so I can use some of the variables I defined in it. My file `setup.php` is at the level seen below

```
wp-admin
wp-content
   .
   .
   themes
       .
       .
       mytheme
           .
           .
           setup.php
           .
       .
   .
wp-includes
.
.
wp-config.php
.
.
```

and the file begins with

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

include '../../wp-config.php';

$con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
```

and the error I'm getting is

> Warning: include(../../wp-config.php): failed to open stream: No such
>   file or directory

I tried doing

```
include_once get_home_path() . 'wp-config.php';
```

but `get_home_path()` is undefined, which means that in order to use it I'd have to include the file in which it was defined, which is a circular problem because, as this thread shows, I don't know how to pull in files at different levels.

Any help in solving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are developing a theme, you shouldn't need to manually include `wp_config.php`, WordPress will handle that for you. Furthermore, I would *STRONGLY* recommend looking in to the [proper way to access the database via WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)' actions & hooks; I can't think of a whole lot of reasons you would need to hit it directly, and even if you did, [using global $wpdb and the methods available to that object](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) will handle everything else.

Answer (score 0):

You need to jump up one more level...

1. mytheme
2. themes
3. wp-content

Three levels up, so 3 x `../`:

```
 include_once '../../../wp-config.php
```

...that being said (and though I *can* think of situations justifying what you are doing), I too have a feeling you are doing things in a very wrong way for no good reasons.

Read Ceilis answer and consider one more time if what you are doing is strictly necessary.

Comment: I didn't say I couldn't think of ANY reasons, just not a whole lot :)